# Get File Location using __DIR__

Tags: php, function, directory

```
$appRoot = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))));
require $appRoot . '/app/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

I am running the above functions. But I am not able to get the path of the outcome locations of autoload and bootstrap.php file. Can someone help me what will be the final location of the files which are used in the require functions.

```
C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\functional\utils
```

This is my current location of the file in which this code is written

Comment: where do you have the app folder?

Comment: app is parallel to dev

Comment: I have written an answer for you

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not able to locate the 2 require files. Can you update answer with location of bootstrap.php and autoload.php which are require

Comment: where do you have autoload.php ?

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\vendor is the location of autload which I know, but what will the location of files as per above code?

Comment: edited the answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
__DIR__
```

gives the current directory of the file. Hence in your case

```
__DIR__ = C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\functional\utils
```

dirname($var) gives the direct of a file or directory passed in as a parameter. Hence

```
dirname(__DIR__) = C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev\tests\functional
```

if you apply this iteratively you need

```
dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)))
```

which refers to the C:\wamp64\www\magento2252\dev directory but you have used dirname 4 times

So you code should look like this

```
$appRoot = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
require $appRoot . '/app/bootstrap.php';
require $appRoot . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```